# How to show empty view with Paging 3 library in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-paging-3

I want to show empty view when paging3 is loaded with an empty list.

It seems to work with following code.  Is this the proper way to do with the paging 3 library?:

```
        adapter?.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            adapter?.apply {
                if (itemCount <= 0 && !loadState.source.refresh.endOfPaginationReached) {
                    Timber.d("==> to show empty view")
                    tvEmptyView.isGone = false
                } else {
                    Timber.d("==> to hide empty view")
                    tvEmptyView.isGone = true
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly plug into the adapter loadStateFlow, e.g

```
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
        adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest { loadStates ->
            val refresher = loadStates.refresh
            val displayEmptyMessage =  (refresher is LoadState.NotLoading && refresher.endOfPaginationReached && adapter.itemCount == 0)
            layoutBinding.emptyStateMessage.isVisible = displayEmptyMessage
            layoutBinding.emptyStateImage.isVisible = displayEmptyMessage
            layoutBinding.swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = refresher is LoadState.Loading
        }
    }
```

Comment: For some reason `loadStates.refresh.endOfPaginationReached` not worked for me. I have to use `loadStates.append.endOfPaginationReached` (**`append`**) just like @Florian Walther answered.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
if (loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading &&
    loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached &&
    adapter.itemCount < 1
) {
   recyclerView.isVisible = false
   textViewEmpty.isVisible = true
} else {
    textViewEmpty.isVisible = false
}
```

Comment: Your solution is just like mine; but since Paul posted his solution first, I marked his as the solution.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use a concatAdapter to display the empty view **below** the normal results if they are less than 11. Unfortunately paging 3 library will give me many false positive results regarding the `LoadState.NotLoading` and `loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached` States so I had to double check it by introducing a counter. Either Florian's or Paul's answer will work.

```
     offersAdapter.addLoadStateListener { updateUiOnNewLoadSate(it) }
    
     private fun updateUiOnNewLoadSate(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
    
            Timber.i("STATE $loadState")
          
            // Show empty view if results are less or equal 10
            val displayEmptySearch =
                loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && offersAdapter.itemCount <= 10 && loadStatesCounter > 1
            if (displayEmptySearch) {
    //here I display the empty view as a part of the
   //infinite scrolling recyclerview by using concatAdapter
                concatAdapter.addAdapter(emptyViewAdapter)
            } else {
                concatAdapter.removeAdapter(emptyViewAdapter)
            }
            loadStatesCounter++ //only apply above block when loadStatesCounter > 1
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `adapter.itemCount < 1` to avoid a false positive before the data has loaded from the Flow

Comment: Good catch Florian this also kinda worked but according to my logic I had to reverse the operator like this `adapter.itemCount > 1` This introduces another issue though. When there is a single result it won't display the empty view. So I'm keeping the counter for now.